# php include problem with urls with options ?view=task&others file not found

Tags: php, include

I really have read the other articles that cover this subject. But I seem to be in a slightly different position. I'm not using modrewrite (other articles).

I would like to 'include' a webpage its a 'Joomla php' generated page inside a php script. I'd hoped to make additions on the 'fly' without altering the original script. So I was going to 'precomplete' elements of the page by parasing the page once it was included I hadent wanted to hack the original script. To the point I can't include the file and its not because the path is wrong -

so
include ("/home/public_html/index.php"); this would work
include ("/home/public_html/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&task=add");  this would not!

I've tried a variety of alternates, in phrasing, I can't use the direct route "http:etc..." since its a current php version so must be a reference to the same server. I tried relative, these work without the ?option=com_k2&view=item&task=add

It may be the simple answer that 'options' or variables can be passed. 
Or that the include can't be used to 'wait' for a page to be generated - i.e. it will only return the html.

I'm not the biggest of coders but I've done alot more than this and I thought this was so basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this would work include ("/home/public_html/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&task=add"); this would not!

And it never will: You are mixing a filesystem path with GET parameters, which can be passed only through the web server (utilizing a `http://` call... But that, in turn, won't run the PHP code the way you want.)

You could set the variables beforehand:

```
 $option = "com_k2";
 $view =   "item";
 $task =   "add";
```

include the file the normal way:

```
 include ("/home/public_html/index.php");
```

this is assuming that you have access to the file, and can change the script to expect variables instead of GET parameters.

Comment: Of course you CAN include by URL, but this is of course very VERY bad design because of security issues.  I only mention it because Andrew may find this out on his own, and I want to be clear that it is a very very bad idea.

Comment: Thankyou. I really had not wanted to alter the file, just add to it! but it looks like it may not be.. thankyou - and Brad thumbs up for the security - I've read enough about this topic to discover the bad side of turning off certain php features! cheers... Andy.